# How to insert every Single date into table

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, time

I want to insert every date of any year from combo box or list box by click or select  as like 1/1/2021 to 12/31/2021. I use ms access application software. Im not programmer but i try to learn coding and keep my data in my databases as smartly. Someone   can help me please.

Comment: in a nut shell: convert start date to number (usually number of secs since some epoch), add the numerical equivalent of 1 day for 0 up to 364 days (will likely need to convert from secs), and print each value as a date.  Some languages let you add date/time directly.  Start and post that code (this forum does not generally write the code for you)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Always add tags for the tool and programming language that you are using to attract those who know about them (or chances are they will miss your question).